# MIN_INT in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, int

I'm puzzled I can't find a constant for the minimum value of `int` in actionscript.

There's `Number.MIN_VALUE`, but, as the name implies, that's for `Number`, not for `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, that's `int.MIN_VALUE` -.-

Comment: I'm leaving this self-answer assuming it will help someone else who tried to google it and failed, like I did.